# What is the use of setvbuf in an application(executable)?

Tags: windows

```
setvbuf (stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, 0);
```

This line is present in one of my codes and I am not able to figure out why. If I comment out this line, my app works fine. But if I keep it, then my app crashes. Also read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86cebhfs(v=vs.100).aspx, but not able to understand properly, as to why the application is crashing.

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the MSDN description for `setvbuf()` says:

[image]

So, on Windows, you will get the same effect as `_IOFBF`, which, as it says in the text, will use an automatically allocated buffer of the size you specified.

In your code, you specified a size of *zero*. Hence the crash.

On non-Win32 systems, the same command would activate line buffering and so possibly would be ok. Perhaps this code is multi-platform?

Comment: +1 (Beat me to it.) IOW, this line of code is wasted space in the source code. :-)

Comment: @Roger Yes, this is originally for UNIX/linux families..I wanted it for Windows